# How to text wrap into quicksight tables graph

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have a column where text is really big I want to text into quicksight pivot tables graph?
Since my taxt is really big extended graph size will not help

Answer (score 1):

Text wrapping is now a simple format option for tables and pivot tables as shown in the image linked below. However, the text will NOT wrap unless you make the "Row height" bigger as well which will set the height of ALL rows, wrapped or not. In the example image I have set the row height to be 50 (default is one line or 25 pixels) and this will allow two lines of text to wrap. Cheers.

[Format box for Quicksight Tables with wrap option and row height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKbrq.png)